# Listing all jpg files except ending with certain character in command line CMD

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

I want to `echo` all `*.jpg` files, except for `*-.jpg`, so for that I made this command:

```
for %i in (*.jpg) do if not "%i"=="*-.jpg" echo %~i
```

But it failed, because it echoed all jpg files.

To experiment I wrote this command:

```
for %i in (*.jpg) do if not "%i"=="*.jpg" echo %~i
```

I was expecting this command to echo no files, but it does echo jpg files despite the `if not` command.

What am I missing?

Update:

My goal is to rewrite my batch file with this content:

```
for %%i in (*.jpg) do magick "%%i" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB "%%~ni"-.jpg
```

so that it makes the compression operation, only if the filename doesn't end with `-`.

I tried this with no success and successory investigations which led to this question:

```
for %%i in (*.jpg) do if not "%%ni"=="*-.jpg" magick "%%i" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB "%%~ni"-.jpg
```

Comment: If not what? Obviouly, no file will have `*.jpg` as name, that is, in cmd command line (nor Batch files) `*` does _not_ match several characters, excepting as parameters of a few commands!. Use: `cmd /V /C for %i in (*.jpg) do @(set "name=%i" ^& if "!name:~-5!" neq "-.jpg" echo %i)` instead... It is simpler in a Batch file!

Comment: `if` does not feature wildcards like `*` or `?` (except for `if exist`)…

Comment: It would be better if you were to tell us exactly what your real intention was, because printing filenames to the console does not really constitute a useful task. If you were copying or moving them for instance, you could use `robocopy` with its `/xf` option and `*-.jpg`, e.g. `robocopy . destination *.jpg /xf *-.jpg >nul`. You could even use it just to list them, e.g. `robocopy . ~ *.jpg /l /nc /ndl /njh /njs /np /ns /xf *-.jpg` or in a [tag:for-loop] with filenames only: `for /f %i in ('robocopy . ~ *.jpg /l /nc /ndl /njh /njs /np /ns /xf *-.jpg') do @echo %~nxi`.

Comment: @Compo, I have updated my post

Comment: @aschipfl this explains why it doesn't work. At least I know that.

Comment: Yes you have @AndrewAnderson, you've changed your code from that entered in a [[tag:command-line-interface]] to that used in a [[tag:windows]] [[tag:batch-file]]. I've fixed your poor choices of tags for you, and formatted your code properly too.

Comment: In a Batch file it is simpler: `for %%i in (*.jpg) do (` line `set "name=%%i"` line `if not "!name:~-5!"=="-.jpg" magick "%%i" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB "%%~Ni"-.jpg` line `)`  Don't forget to include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the filenames through `find.exe` and omit those that contain -.jpg. The /V switch tells `find.exe` to omit lines where the string is found. Using `findstr.exe` uses a regex which can ensure that it is only found at the end of the filename. As always, use `FIND /?` and `FINDSTR /?` to read all about it.

```
DIR /B /A:-D "*.jpg" | "%SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe" /V "-.jpg"
    or
DIR /B /A:-D "*.jpg" | "%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe" /V /R "\-\.jpg$"
```

If you want to step up to a modern day language, it is easy in PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.jpg' | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch '\-\.jpg$' }
```

**Updated question, updated answer**

When the `magick` command line appears as you wish, remove the `ECHO` at the beginning of the line.

```
SET "EXT=jpg"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /B /A:-D "*.%EXT%" ^| "%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe" /V /R "\-\.%EXT%$"') DO (
    ECHO magick "%%~A" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB "%%~nA-.%EXT%"
)
```

In PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.jpg' |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch '\-\.jpg$' } |
    ForEach-Object {
        & magick "$_.FullName" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB ("$_.BaseName" + "-.jpg")
    }
```

Comment: How can I make a for loop on ```DIR /B /A:-D "*.jpg" | find /V "-.jpg"```? Can I?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, why do you need a `FOR` loop? Have you tried running one of these command lines? In what way does this not work as you expected?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, I see that you have changed the question.

Comment: This should work, but it doesn't:
```FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR /B /A:-D "*.jpg" | find /V "-.jpg"`) do magick "%%i" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB "%%~ni"-.jpg```.
I used the answer for this question: https://superuser.com/questions/983510/exclude-a-file-name-in-for-loop

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, saying ".should work, but it doesn't" does not give anyone anything to go on. You failed to escape the VERTICAL LINE with a CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. Just searched this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final batch file:
`` FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`DIR /B /A:-D "*.jpg" ^| find /V "-.jpg"`) DO magick "%%i" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB "%%~ni"-.jpg ``

For reference:
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/Windows/System32/cmd_exe/commands/for/f/command/index
https://ss64.com/nt/for.html